# Extract certain key value pairs from data type 'array<map<string,string>>' , in HIVE

Tags: sql, arrays, hive, maps, explode

I have a table that has two columns: ***ID*** and ***arr_map_col***. The ***arr_map_col*** is of `array<map<string,string>>` data type and I need to extract certain key and their values from it. This is the code to create the table:

```
select stack(5,
             12,array(map('PA_Type', 'Sent', 'PA_Card', '115286', 'PA_Date', '202403', 'PA_Status', 'Done')),
             14,array(map('PA_Type', 'Rec', 'PA_Card', '226254', 'PA_Date', '202401', 'PA_Status', 'Done')),
             19,array(map('PA_Type', 'Fol', 'PA_Card', '152644', 'PA_Date', '202312', 'PA_Status', 'Pen')),
             21, array(map('PA_Type', 'Sent', 'PA_Card', '556253', 'PA_Date', '202311', 'PA_Status', 'Comp'), map('PA_Type', 'Rec', 'PA_Card', '126353', 'PA_Date', '202402')),
             11, array(map('PA_Type', 'Fol', 'PA_Card', '225483', 'PA_Date', '202311', 'PA_Status', 'Pen'), map('PA_Type', 'Sent', 'PA_Card', '353154', 'PA_Date', ''))
             
            ) as (id, arr_map_col)
```

For every ID, I need to extract '*PA_Type*' and '*PA_card*' from the '***arr_map_col***' column. The output should be like below:

[image: Output]